# Is this analogy in Reisheis Chokmah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, gehinnom

I've heard of a analogy that may or may not be in [the sefer Reisheis Chokmah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reshit_Chochmah), that in a part of gehennom, "sinners" cut, in a forest where they see ghosts, wood for a burning fire. Does anyone have the source for this, or if it even exists in the sefer?

Comment: sam, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! You could make the question easier to answer and more valuable to readers by [edit]ing in more information about where you heard this idea and why you are interested in sourcing it, as well as bibliographic information about *Reisheis Chokmah*, which I, for one, haven't merited to encounter to date. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557) to more of the site's features.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Here's the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reshit_Chochmah), and here's a [copy from HebrewBooks](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14032&st=&pgnum=1). It's a long and fascinating multi-part *sefer*.

Comment: @Fred thanks. The only _Reshis Chochma_ I'd been familiar with is the one that teaches newbies to read Hebrew. (Like _Alef Bina_.)